# Append a variable in the last digits of an IP Address on bash script

Tags: bash, ssh

So can i connect via SSH on every IP Address in a network using a while loop and then appending the counter inside that loop at the end of the IP like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 0 -lt 1]
do
    a=`expr $a + 1`
    ssh user@172.18.10.$a
    echo connected
done
```

I'm almost sure it's wrong, so I'm trying to find the correct way to do it.
Can it be done in an easier way, maybe using the ARP table like a list and cycling trough it?

Comment: you have missing space in `[ 0 -lt 1 ]`, is it mistyping?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. yeah sorry

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `ssh` line. You should learn to use `bash` arithmetic expressions instead of `expr`, though.

Comment: You have an infinite loop. `0 -lt 1` will always be true. It should be something like `while [ $a -lt 256 ]`

Comment: Or you can use `for $a in {1..255}`

Comment: `expr` for arithmetic isn't necessary in any modern, POSIX-compliant shell. Use `a=$((a+1))` instead. `bash` also has C-style for loops: `for ((a=1; a<=255; i++)); do`.

Comment: So, what happens if the network mask isn't a `/24`? A network with a mask length of 23 or 25 would totally blow your scheme. The only accurate way to get the addresses in a network is to use the binary address and network mask which are each 32-bit unsigned integers.

Comment: Thx very much for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in $(seq 255)
do
    ssh user@172.18.10.$a true
    echo "Connected to 172.18.10.$a"
done
```

`seq 255` outputs a sequence of numbers from 1 to 255 that then for iterates over setting the variable `a` to each value.

`true` in the ssh command is to tell ssh to execute a command and then exit. If you do not specify a command, it will start an interactive session and not end until you exit it. You can substitute it with any command you want to be executed on each host.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to check if the connection was successful you need something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in $(seq 255)
do
    ssh user@172.18.10.$a true && echo "Connected to 172.18.10.$a"
done
```